# How to connect 4-pin LED cable to the 4-pin power supply without soldering?

Tags: connector, led-driver, led-strip

How can I connect a 4-pin LED extension cable to the 4-pin power source without soldering? What type of connecter can be used here? (the following two cables should be connected)

[image]
[image]

I think it's not possible to directly insert 4 heads of wire into the 4 holes, they will just not be fixed there. I think I need a connection in between.

The following connector is available, but it's only useful for connecting two LED strips together:

[image]

Another option is to use one of the following jumpers, but that requires soldering. I am looking for a solution without soldering:

[image]

The following connector is also available, but it is intended to be used for connecting the 4-pin cable to a 4-pin LED strip, like the picture:

[image]
[image]

Is there any other kind of connector that can be used here? It's worth mentioning that the power supply is 12V:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If finding the mating connector from the manufacturer isn't an option, then you should be able to get some of those Dupont pin jumpers and wire-nut them onto the leads coming out of your wall wart.  It won't be very secure, but doesn't require replacing the existing connector.

If you don't mind replacing the connector, your options open up.  I would suggest a mating pair of terminal blocks like so:

[image: terminal block]

They use a screw cage to clamp the wires so all you need is a screwdriver.

Image from Newark.

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be easier if you used an extension cable with the appropriate connecters directly, but if the connector on the power supply uses standard female pin header, then you can add Dupont connectors to your cable with a crimping tool.

You can look up "dupont connector kit", that should give you plenty of options. You'll need the crimping tool to add the pins to the end of each of the wires of your cable, so it'll probably be the ~$30 kits rather than the ~$10 versions. It requires a bit of practice to correctly crimp the connectors. You then insert the pins into a 4-pin connector.

The kit should also contain the female counterpart you'll need for the other end.